# Enter Key Will Not Function As Button

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried all the code I can, and Have not figured out how to make it when I click the `<i>`, or when I hit enter it works. I really need help. Thanks!

```js
$('#update').click(function upd() {
 loadChannel($('#chnlname').val());
});

var input = document.getElementById("chnlname");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    loadChannel($('#chnlname').val());
   }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Search1">
    <div class="inputWithIcon">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Channel ID" id="chnlname" class="Input2"></input>
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" id="update" onclick="upd()"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- add your js code in document ready method
2- no need to specify click handler in html code, $('#update').click is sufficient.

complete code: https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/xaemMr

js;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#update').click(function upd() {
            loadChannel($('#chnlname').val());
        });
        function loadChannel() {
            console.log("loading channel");
        }
        var input = document.getElementById("chnlname");

        input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                loadChannel($('#chnlname').val());
            }
        });
    });
```

html:

```
 <div class="Search1">
    <div class="inputWithIcon">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Channel ID" id="chnlname" class="Input2"></input>
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" id="update"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Enter Key still did not work. However, in the console it did have "loading channel", I believe it is somehow not loading the text in the box.

Comment: @MtnBros i wrote a mock loadChannel method which prints "loading channel", so I could test whether it works.  I thought you have the implemention of this method in your code.

Comment: I placed my code in the wrong location, meaning it did not work. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1) Ensure that your click function is defined, and accessible when the DOM loads. It looks like your function `upd(){}` isn't available in a global context. Though it doesn't follow best practices, You could accomplish this by binding the click function to the window object.
See Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/js03rq2b/42/

2) You have called `upd(){}` in the HTML via `onclick="upd()"`, while also trying to add an event listener in the JavaScript. Use one of these methods, but not both.

3) Additionally, if you bind your click handler to a `<button>` tag instead of an `<i>` tag, it will respond to SPACEBAR and ENTER as well. Whenever possible, capitalize on default browser behavior by using semantic markup.

Hope that helps.